# How to prevent flutter dialog and showModalBottomSheet to pops up after navigation

Tags: flutter, navigation, dialog

In my flutter project, I used alert dialog and showModalBottomSheet and I wand to prevent these widgets from displaying after navigating to another screen.

I used `if(mounted)` but it is not working
any advice to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Navigator.pop(context);` before navigate another screen.

For example

```
Alert(
...

Navigator.pop(context);

Navigator.push(AnotherScreen);

);
```

Comment: I don't want to close it I want it to appear only on the specific screen if I navigate to another one it doesn't pop up.

Comment: you can send bool value if its true or false you can pop up